# Dealing with images in android

Tags: android

I am working on an app that shows a large number of images like 100 in the first view the 4 images after you click each image. I am not willing to use any server or database. I can create the layout using a grid view but how do i add 100 images to an app? And then 4 to each image . The basic thing will be like an amazon or flipkart website .

This project is very important for me so please help as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all 100 images to drawable folder. Naming them from id1 to id100 for easy access in Java code with R.drawable.id#

Comment: But that will take a lot of time as there are 4 more images after you click one image.